# flutter how to get the data from webservice with xml body

Tags: fetch

i have the below body from a webservice

This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

```
<Schedule xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Viptech">
<Entries>
<ScheduleEntry>
<Arrival>2020-03-17T11:31:00</Arrival>
<CutOff i:nil="true"/>
<Departure>2020-03-18T11:31:00</Departure>
<Line>SALLAUM LINES DMCC</Line>
<Port>Cotonou</Port>
<TerminalCode>COT</TerminalCode>
<Vessel>Arabian Sea</Vessel>
<Voyage>20AR02</Voyage>
</ScheduleEntry>
<ScheduleEntry>
<Arrival>2020-04-02T23:31:00</Arrival>
<CutOff i:nil="true"/>
<Departure>2020-04-04T11:31:00</Departure>
<Line>SALLAUM LINES DMCC</Line>
<Port>Cotonou</Port>
<TerminalCode>COT</TerminalCode>
<Vessel>SILVER RAY</Vessel>
<Voyage>20SR02</Voyage>
</ScheduleEntry>
</Entries>
</Schedule>
```

and i try to get the data from this web service, i try many methode but i get any erreur, finaly i do the below code but i get the same erreur
the code is

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:xml2json/xml2json.dart';

class SchedulesPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const SchedulesPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<SchedulesPage> createState() => _SchedulePageState();
}

class _SchedulePageState extends State<SchedulesPage> {
  Future fetchXmlData() async {
    var url =
        Uri.parse(',,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,');

    final response = await http.get(url);
    final xmlstring = response.body;
    final Xml2Json xml2json = Xml2Json();
    xml2json.parse(xmlstring);
    var jsonstring = xml2json.toParker();
    var data = jsonDecode(jsonstring);

    return data;
    print(data.toString());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Schedule'),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: TextButton.icon(
          onPressed: () {
            fetchXmlData();
          },
          icon: Icon(Icons.search),
          label: Text('Print Data'),
        ),
      ), //FutureBuilder<String>(
      //   future: fetchXmlData(),
      //   builder: (context, snapshot) {
      //     if (snapshot.hasData) {
      //       final xmlData = snapshot.data;
      //       parseXmlData(xmlData!);
      //       return Text('XML data fetched and parsed');
      //     } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
      //       return Text('Error fetching XML data');
      //     }
      //     return CircularProgressIndicator();
      //   },
      // ),
    );
  }
}
```

and the error is
E/flutter (27356): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Xml2JsonException: message = parse error - invalid XML
please someone have a soultion,

in the first, i try to get data from xml directly, but i didnt success after i try to convert the xml to json and i get the final erreur